# python Websockets (asyncio ver) force close connection

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

I am coding for python >3.5.
I am using Websockets 6.0 library that is here:
  https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets
I have been call them the `asyncio` Websockets since they are based on asyncio.
In my search there were a lot of "lost connections", but I am looking at how to cancel a current `ws.recv()`.
A call to the `.start()` creates a helper thread to start the asynico event loop. Then the receive function start and calls the connect function and websocket `ws` is instanced. Then the receive functions works fall messages. When I am ready to stop, a .stop() is called. I was expecting the stop funciton to stop the awaited `ws.recv()`. Then with the keep_running flag set to false and running a `ws.close()`, I would expect the `ws.recv()` to end and the when keep_running loop to end. That is not what is happening.  I see all three stops, but never the `receive stop`.

```
command is: stop
Do command is stopped
Stop 1
Stop 2
Stop 3
^CException ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1294, in _shutdown
    t.join()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1056, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1072, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
(pyalmondplus) Pauls-MBP:pyalmondplus paulenright$
```

Code for reference:

```
import threading
import asyncio
import websockets
import json

class PyAlmondPlus:
    def __init__(self, api_url, event_callback=None):
        self.api_url = api_url
        self.ws = None
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.receive_task = None
        self.event_callback = event_callback
        self.keep_running = False

    async def connect(self):
        print("connecting")
        if self.ws is None:
            print("opening socket")
            self.ws = await websockets.connect(self.api_url)
        print(self.ws)

    async def disconnect(self):
        pass

    async def send(self, message):
        pass

    async def receive(self):
        print("receive started")
        while self.keep_running:
            if self.ws is None:
                await self.connect()
            recv_data = await self.ws.recv()
            print(recv_data)
        print("receive ended")

    def start(self):
        self.keep_running = True
        print("Start 1")
        print("Start 2")
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.start_loop, args=())
        print("Start 3")
        t.start()
        print("Receiver running")

    def start_loop(self):
        print("Loop helper 1")
        policy = asyncio.get_event_loop_policy()
        policy.set_event_loop(policy.new_event_loop())
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.loop.set_debug(True)
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.receive())
        print("Loop helper 2")

    def stop(self):
        print("Stop 1")
        self.keep_running = False
        print("Stop 2")
        self.ws.close()
        print("Stop 3")
```

Comment: Thanks Harrison, what is the markdown to do that? 
Also, good catch for adding the extra tag. I was looking at different websockets and could not find a good one.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking at how to cancel a current ws.recv() [...] I see all three stops, but never the receive stop.

Your `receive` coroutine is likely suspended waiting for some data to arrive, so it's not in a position to check the `keep_running` flag.

The easy and robust way to stop a running coroutine is to `cancel` the asyncio [`Task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) that drives it. That will immediately un-suspend the coroutine and make whatever it was waiting for raise a `CancelledError`. When using cancel you don't need a `keep_running` flag at all, the exception will terminate the loop automatically.

> A call to the .start() creates a helper thread to start the asynico event loop.

This works, but you don't really need a new thread and a whole new event loop for each instance of `PyAlmondPlus`. Asyncio is designed to run inside a single thread, so one event loop instance can host any number of coroutines.

Here is a possible design that implements both ideas (not tested with actual web sockets):

```
# pre-start a single thread that runs the asyncio event loop
bgloop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
_thread = threading.Thread(target=bgloop.run_forever)
_thread.daemon = True
_thread.start()

class PyAlmondPlus:
    def __init__(self, api_url):
        self.api_url = api_url
        self.ws = None

    async def connect(self):
        if self.ws is None:
            self.ws = await websockets.connect(self.api_url)

    async def receive(self):
        # keep_running is not needed - cancel the task instead
        while True:
            if self.ws is None:
                await self.connect()
            recv_data = await self.ws.recv()

    async def init_receive_task(self):
        self.receive_task = bgloop.create_task(self.receive())

    def start(self):
        # use run_coroutine_threadsafe to safely submit a coroutine
        # to the event loop running in a different thread
        init_done = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(
            self.init_receive_task(), bgloop)
        # wait for the init coroutine to actually finish
        init_done.result()

    def stop(self):
        # Cancel the running task. Since the event loop is in a
        # background thread, request cancellation with
        # call_soon_threadsafe.
        bgloop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.receive_task.cancel)
```